# ActionBar color stuck to white when set dynamically

Tags: android, sdk, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change dynamically ActionBar background color but every time it gets stuck on a white background... I tried creating a ColorDrawable with an int color, parse it from a String, even creating a drawable in my XML with a solid green color, but when I call

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable()
```

with the method I choose, it becomes white, no matter what I do. Any idea on why this happens?

In my XML I use a custom style to add a background to my ActionBar, I tried to remove but it's the same result...

What I tested so far as parameter for setBackgroundDrawable is:

- `new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));`
- `new ColorDrawable(Color.parse("#FF4444"));`
- `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);`

Comment: What do you put inside the `setBackgroundDrawable()` call?

Comment: edited answer so it's more complete

Comment: Are you using a the android actionbar or sherlock bar?

Comment: Normal Android ActionBar